# Make NicEdit appear in all instances given the same ID

Tags: javascript, php, nicedit

I am trying to get `NicEdi`t to work only for all textareas with IDs of `'r_desc'`. Currently this occurs only for the first instance of a form that is generated within a while loop, and not the others. What am I doing wrong?

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        nicEditors.editors.push(
            new nicEditor().panelInstance(
                document.getElementById('r_desc')
            )
        );
    });
    </script>
```

**PHP/HTML**

```
$i=0;
while($i<5){ ?>
<form id="content" name="content" method="POST" action="index.php">
   <textarea name="r_type" id="textarea"></textarea>
   <textarea name="r_desc" id="r_desc"></textarea>
   <textarea name="r_rate" id="textarea"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" id="button" value="Update" />
</form>
<? $i++;
}
```

***I have also tried:***

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByID("r_desc");
    for(var i=0;i<textareas.length;i++)
     {
        var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
        myNicEditor.panelInstance(textareas[i]);

     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements are supposed to have unique IDs. The implementation of `getElementById` knows this and will only return the first element that matches the given ID.

You need to use a different approach of identifying elements that you want converted to `Nicedit`

If you use something like `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName` instead (note that these return elementS not just an element)

**PHP:**

```
$i=0;
while($i<5){ ?>
<form id="content" name="content" method="POST" action="index.php">
   <textarea name="r_type" class="to-nice"></textarea>
   <textarea name="r_desc" ></textarea>
   <textarea name="r_rate" class="to-nice"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" id="button" value="Update" />
</form>
<? $i++;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("to-nice");
```